# Assignment and Conditional check in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

I came across this below program and I don't understand the output.

Can someone please shed some light on it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=1,j=1;
  for(;j;printf("%d %d\n",i,j))
  j=i++ <=5;
  return 0;
}
```

And its output is:

```
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
6 1
7 0
```

Comment: Fyi, single-stepping this *very* short program in a debugger would tell you a novel of information on its behavior. Debuggers can be *very* powerful in understanding how something *works*, not just figuring out how something is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=1,j=1;

  //for(initialisation; condition; operations)
  // here no initialisation, 
  // 1. condition is j, if j is true 
  // 2. then it will execute block statements 
  // 3. then finally it execute operations, here printf
  // 4. again check step 1.

  for(;j;printf("%d %d\n",i,j))
  j=i++ <=5;  // j = (i <= 5); i++;
  return 0;
}
```

Your question can be simplified as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i=1,j=1;
  while(j) {   
    j = (i++ <=5);
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ajay have given an alternative code to the original one (I'll copy-paste it below for convenience)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=1,j=1;
  while(j) {   
    j = (i++ <=5);
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, let's look at the execution of the while loop

i=1, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (1 <= 5) = true = 1, i=2 (post increment).

i=2, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (2 <= 5) = true = 1, i=3 (post increment).

i=3, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (3 <= 5) = true = 1, i=4 (post increment).

i=4, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (4 <= 5) = true = 1, i=5 (post increment)

i=5, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (5 <= 5) = true = 1, i=6 (post increment).

i=6, j=1, j is True, in loop, j = (6 <= 5) = false = 0, i=7 (post increment).

i=7, j=0, j is False, out of loop.

Program Stops.

Hope this execution explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement:

```
j=i++ <=5;
```

evaluates the value of the variable `i` before incrementing it. This evaluated value is used in the comparison `<= 5`. The result of a comparison will be either `0` or `1` depending whether the condition is *false* or *true* respectively.

In this case, it has the same effect as writing it in two separate statements:

```
j = i <= 5;
++i;
```

Comment: Note that comparison operator `<=` has higher precedence than the assigment operator `=`. Therefore, comparison takes place before assignment.

Answer (score 1):

syntax of `for` loop:

```
for (initialization Statement; check condition; increment/decrements operation)
{
       // codes 
}
```

The **initialization statement** is executed only once. Then, the **check condition** is evaluated. If the condition is **true (nonzero)**, then codes inside the body of for loop is executed and the update expression is updated. if condition is **false(0)**, then for loop terminated.

In your code,

`j = 1` then condition become **true** and enter into body of `for` loop. Then, check
`j = i++ <= 5 = true`, and control goes to **increment/decrements operation** part and print `i = 2` and `j = 1`.

then, again code repeated until the test condition is **false**.

Answer (score 1):

Same can be represent in this manner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=1,j=1;j!=0;){
    j=i++ <=5;
    printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

here, as per convention of `for` loop.

1. i & j is initialized to 1
2. check condition whether `j != 0`
3. `i <= 5` so j remains 1 && i becomes 2 (after increment)
4. prints `i = 2, j =1`
5. again, `i <= 5` so j remains 1 && i becomes 3 (after increment)
6. prints `i = 3, j =1`
7. again, `i <= 5` so j remains 1 && i becomes 4 (after increment)
8. prints `i = 4, j =1`
9. and this goes on, it j becomes 0, as it violent the condition as i becomes greater than 5